# Select Top 1 field and assign to local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to take the value of ExtractedDate from this query and use it as  @LastExtractDate in the next query.
How do I do that?

```
    SELECT TOP 1 [ExtractedDate]
    FROM [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex] order by ExtractedDate desc
```

next query:

```
    insert into @table(Hex, KeyDeviceId, ObjectDateTime, ExtractedDate  )
SELECT     CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ObjectValue, 1)) AS Hex, KeyDeviceId, ObjectDateTime , GETDATE ()
    FROM         SQLPending
    WHERE     (ObjectSubType LIKE '%GAS%') and (ObjectDateTime > @LastExtractDate)
```

Comment: why not pick an answer after all these years haha

Answer (score 165):

why not use this:

```
declare @LastExtractDate date
SELECT TOP 1 @LastExtractDate=[ExtractedDate]
FROM [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex] order by ExtractedDate desc
```

Comment: This syntax is not correct. You will get NULL value in Sql Server if you try to run this code. You need to assign the value to the variable from a subquery. Example: `declare @SomeVar varchar(100) = (select top 1 someCol from someTable)`

Comment: @Hamster - it would appear at least 164 people (at the time of writing) disagree with you. It works for me... can you give an example of it not working?

Answer (score 25):

Simply declare & assign:

```
DECLARE @LastExtractDate DATETIME = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [ExtractedDate] FROM [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex] order by ExtractedDate desc
)
```

or better:

```
DECLARE @LastExtractDate DATETIME = (
    SELECT MAX(ExtractedDate) FROM [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex]
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @ExtractedDate DATETIME
SET  @ExtractedDate = (SELECT    TOP 1 ExtractedDate
                       FROM      [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex]
                       ORDER BY  ExtractedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this simply

```
declare @LastExtractDate date 
SELECT @LastExtractDate=MAX([ExtractedDate])
FROM [OnsiteV4].[dbo].[SqlPendingIndex]
```